# How to do hierarchical child count for a set of IDs in PostgreSQL (not a single ID)

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper

I am using this SQL to retrieve hierarchical children count for a comment:

```
WITH RECURSIVE c AS (
    SELECT "Id", "ParentId"
    FROM public."Comments"
    WHERE "ParentId" = @CommentId
    UNION
    SELECT s."Id", e."ParentId"
    FROM public."Comments" e
    INNER JOIN c s ON s."Id" = e."ParentId"
) SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM c;
```

It works as expected.

But how can I transform this SQL to work with a list of IDs, so it returns a dictionary where KEY is an ID from list in parameters and VALUE is a hierarchical count of children?

I am using this SQL with Dapper in C#

Sample "comments" table:

```
id  | parentId 
---------------
1   | null
2   | 1
3   | 2
4   | null
5   | 4
6   | 5
7   | 5
```

Input:
Array of IDs given to DB

```
[1, 4]
```

Output:
Dictionary which has ID from input as key and hierarchical children count as value

```
{1: 2, 4: 3}
```

P.S.: the code in input and output is just pseudocode

Comment: Sample data and desired outputs would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query to get the result set

```
WITH RECURSIVE c AS (
    SELECT id, parentId, parentid as sid
    FROM Comments
    WHERE parentId = ANY(Array [1, 4])
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT e.id, e.parentId, s.sid
    FROM Comments e
    INNER JOIN c s ON s.id = e.parentId
) 
SELECT sid, COUNT(*)
FROM c
group by sid;
```

returns

```
sid count
4   3
1   2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected, except for PostgreSQL you need to change 'WHERE column IN (<array>)' to 'WHERE column = ANY(<array>)'

Comment: Updated, using array as a parameter. You may wish to accept the answer to show it was usefull.